# My 2D array isn't reading my text files and outputting correctly

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream

I want to be able to read in letters from a text file into a 2d array. I'm following all the steps, yet my output isn't at all right.

I've tried to initialize the array, I've tried to change the for loops, I've tried to localize my const int values, but nothing works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()
{
    const int ROWS = 5;
    const int COLS = 3;
    ifstream inFile("grades.txt");

    char gradeArray[ROWS][COLS] = {0};

    inFile.open("grades.txt");

    if (!inFile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening the file.";
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            inFile >> gradeArray[i][j];
        }
    }
        cout << gradeArray[0][1];


    inFile.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

TXT FILE (grades.txt in my resource files)

### Edit: The letters each have their own newline. Not sure why they're in the same one.

A
R
B
C
H
G
C
F
S
B
A
A
S
E

## F

## I expect the letter 'R' to be outputted as a test, since that's what I'm asking for in the last cout statement, but I get [ Press any key to continue . . .]. So just a space. Please help. Thanks!

So far I've tried the advice given to me, but it hasn't worked. I'm thinking the file isn't being read correctly? Or the file isn't being outputted correctly...

Comment: `inFile.open("grades.txt");` is redundant. `ifstream inFile("grades.txt");` should have already opened the file.

Comment: Did you try using an ide with a debugger like Visual Studio? Did you get the error message ***Error opening the file.*** printed? Maybe it was printed and the window closed. You seem to use `system("pause");` to keep the window open if the program opened the file but if it failed you have it terminate instantly.

Comment: Do `std::cout.flush()` (or `std::cout << std::flush;`) to make sure your output is flushed to the console before it begins the pause. Another way is to print a `std::endl` after your letter, which prints a new line character `'\n'` and *also* flushes the stream.

Comment: @drescherjm I didn't have the error statement printed at all. And I am using Visual Studio, but I'm very new to coding, and we haven't learned debugging yet, so I thought this could be fixed without it. Also, the error is still the same when I took off the ("grades.txt") from inFile.

Comment: My advice is to learn what the F9, F10, and F11 keys do.

Comment: Move your cursor to the line containing  `exit(1);` and press F9 once. Then debug. I expect it to hit this line and break into the debugger.

Comment: @CruzJean What do you mean by print a endl after my letter? Should I do it after the inFile >> grade... statement? I've tried it and I just got 15 lines of blank in my output. I don't think my file is being read at all...

Comment: @drescherjm When I debug, after toggling the breakpoint, it just shows me the output with the 15 new lines of nothing. I think my code technically works, it's just that my file isn't being read at all.

Comment: ***I've tried it and I just got 15 lines of blank in my output*** That I would not expect. Since you output a single character 1 time outside of your loop. However it appears I was wrong with my guess. Your code does appear to read the file.

Comment: @drescherjm Ah, I've followed CruzJeans advice of putting an endl after every letter. Meaning I put an endl in the nested for loop. That must be why. Nevertheless, nothing really changed.

Comment: ***I'm thinking the file isn't being read correctly?*** My guess is the file's contents is not what you expect.

Comment: I just tested your code locally on Visual Studio 2017 and it printed an `R`. Here is the screen shot: https://ibb.co/VNxvjKm

Comment: WOW. Now I see the ‘R’ since I removed the (“grades.txt”) after the declaration of the inFile. I did try that last time and it didn’t work! However, now that I think about it, I placed my text file under .dat rather than .txt when I tried it. Thanks for your help. If you copy and paste your comment into an actual answer I will then be able to mark it as the solution. Thanks for taking time out of your day to assist me @drescherjm.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC doing `inFile >> gradeArray[i][j]` will capture the whitespace; you should be able to fix this by reading into a string instead which will skip over whitespace; just add `#include <string>` at the top and then in your loop read into the string and get the grade as the first character, something like

```
string line;
inFile >> line;
gradeArray[i][j] = line.empty() ? ' ' : line[0];
```

or whichever character you want to represent missing data.

Comment: So I've included the string library, and turned my array into a string. The new output now shows absolutely nothing. I don't see the "Press any key to continue".

Comment: Again I would say spend 10 minutes to learn what F9, F10, and F11 do. Then you can better understand what is happening.

Comment: No: actually this calls the character extraction operator, which skips white space. You're thinking of `inFile.get()`.

Comment: @drescherjm I tried debugging, but it hasn't given me any info. I assume the compiler thinks that the code works fine, I think my issue is that the file isn't being read at all.

Comment: You need to step through your code 1 line at a time using `F10` and possibly `F11` (if you have functions you don't want to go inside) and look at your variables at each step. The debugger is not supposed to tell you what is wrong. You are supposed to use it to figure that out.

Comment: @drescherjm I just used it. I've gone through all of the code using F10. The error statement has been completely skipped so I assume that means that the file DID open. However as soon as I passed the cout statement after the for loop, nothing outputted from control.

Comment: Did `inFile >> gradeArray[i][j];` execute the 15 times you expect? Did you look at `gradeArray[i][j]` in the local variables when that line executed?

Comment: No it did not. The only reason it was executed 15 times was that I included an endl right after it. Since there is no endl, there are no lines shown. Just a space. I've also double checked my file and I do see the letters there.

Comment: Hi, sorry I probably didn't explain myself very clearly; instead of making gradeArray into a string itself I'm just suggesting you read your input into a string instead of directly into gradeArray, so replacing `infile >> gradeArray[i][j]` with `string line; infile >> line;` and then you can extract the grade from the string with something like `gradeArray[i][j] = line.empty() ? ' ' : line[0];`. I've just tried this on my computer and it seems to work fine, outputting `R`